# How can I turn on haptic feedback on my samsung J3?

Tags: settings, vibration

I just got this phone a week ago and cannot figure out how to turn on haptic feedback. I am using Android 6 and there are no vibration options for the keyboard, only sound options. Is there an app I can download somewhere? Anyone else with a J3 that can help? [image][image]

Comment: This link helps to turn haptic feedback on samsung : http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/skp/faq/1069790. on step 4.3 set vibrate for keyboard

Comment: Thanks for trying Rahul, but that link doesn't have instructions for my OS. Android6. I added pics so you can see I don't have the vibration options to turn on.

Comment: Try using Google keyboard, Gboard, and in Google keyboard settings you can set vibrations